# GRASS-QGIS Linking error

Tags: grass-gis, qgis-plugins

I need a few customizations over grass and would use qgis gui for accessing grass. I am building qgis with grass enabled (WITH_GRASS=TRUE). While I am doing that I get the following.

```
Linking C executable ../../../output/lib/qgis/grass/modules/qgis.g.info
/usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRGetLinearUnits@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `VSIFree@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRExportToWkt@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRGetAttrValue@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `SetCSVFilenameHook@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRExportToProj4@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRIsProjected@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRNewSpatialReference@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRExportToPrettyWkt@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRMorphFromESRI@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRIsGeographic@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRMorphToESRI@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRImportFromProj4@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRGetUTMZone@GDAL_1.8'
/usr/lib/grass64/lib/libgrass_gproj.so: undefined reference to `OSRDestroySpatialReference@GDAL_1.8'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

***
GDAL 1.9.2, released 2012/10/08
GRASS version: GRASS GIS 6.4.2
Python: 2.7.3
Platform: Ubuntu 12.04.1 LTS / x86_64
***
The C compiler identification is GNU
The CXX compiler identification is GNU
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc
Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/gcc -- works
Detecting C compiler ABI info
Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++
Check for working CXX compiler: /usr/bin/c++ -- works
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info
Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
QGIS version: 1.8.0 QGIS (10000)
Found GRASS: /usr/lib/grass64 (6.4.2)
Touch support disabled
Looking for openpty
Looking for openpty - not found
Looking for openpty
Looking for openpty - found
Found Proj: /usr/local/lib/libproj.so
Found GEOS: /usr/lib/libgeos_c.so
Found GDAL: /usr/local/lib/libgdal.so (1.9.2)
Found Expat: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libexpat.so
Found Spatialindex: /usr/lib/libspatialindex.so
Found Qwt: /usr/lib/libqwt-qt4.so (5.2.2)
Found Sqlite3: /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsqlite3.so
Found PostgreSQL: /usr/lib/libpq.so
Looking for Q_WS_X11
Looking for Q_WS_X11 - found
Looking for Q_WS_WIN
Looking for Q_WS_WIN - not found.
Looking for Q_WS_QWS
Looking for Q_WS_QWS - not found.
Looking for Q_WS_MAC
Looking for Q_WS_MAC - not found.
Found Qt4: /opt/QtSDK/Desktop/Qt/4.8.1/gcc/bin/qmake (found suitable version "4.8.1", required is "4.4.0")
Pedantic compiler settings enabled
Found PythonInterp: /usr/bin/python (found version "2.7.3")
Found Python executable: /usr/bin/python
Found Python version: 2.7.3
Found Python library: /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so
Found SIP version: 4.13.2
Found PyQt4 version: 4.9.1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your GRASS was built against GDAL 1.8

Simply, rebuild GRASS with GDAL 1.9.2

Comment: I believe having only one library version of gdal 1.9.2 presently. I remember compiling gdal1.8 sometime back and have overwritten using gdal 1.9.2. Do you think there might be some 1.8 version traces which grass is identifying ? Also I have explicitly mentioned --with-gdal=/usr/local/bin/gdal-config which refers to 1.9.2 and built the grass-6.4.2 which now sits in /usr/local/grass-6.4.2 . I have configured GRASS_INCLUDE_DIR, GRASS_PREFIX, and LIB_PATH to look at /usr/local/grass-6.4.2/lib/libgrass_gproj.so. But some reason it says Found GRASS: /usr/lib/grass64 (6.4.2).

Comment: I have renamed /usr/lib/grass64 to grass64_old. Then its says "Could not find GRASS"

Comment: Your GRASS libs are linked to GDAL 1.8. It is obvious. Of course, you could link the libs back to GDAL 1.9.2 but I would not advise to do that. Again, recompile your GRASS with GDAL 1.9.2. It should solve the problem.

Comment: I have removed /usr/lib/grass64 completly and compiled using 1.9.2. Worked. Thank you.